# how do i identify the encrpytion on an https connection

Tags: ssl, encryption, https

So the way I understand it, when I connect to an HTTPS (443) website I do so through an SSL or TLS encryption. Then, as I understand, there's a bunch of different versions of these protocols like SSL 1.0, 2.0, and TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 etc.

My question is, how can I identify for any given website what sort of encryption they are using?

Comment: How do you hope to use this information? In your web server, an application?

Comment: Hi, thank you for getting back to me. The biggest part of it is just curiosity and just because I want to learn more. The other part has to do with my Firewall and Antivirus' weird behavior with regard to encrypted connections to websites. I can fix the behavior without understanding the details behind the issue, but I want to understand how this stuff works and need to start somewhere. So my first step is to ask how to identify what encryption a website uses.

Comment: There's a difference between SSL/TLS version and the actual encryption algorithm. Each of the versions supports dozens of algorithms. The actual version and cipher suite are negotiated between the peers during the handshake. I suggest you have a look at RFC 2246.

Comment: thank you for the tip I am studying this stuff right now :)